# Which statistical significance test should I use to solve this?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

Which statistical significance test can i use. all are binary outcomes. 
Here is my table. I would like to know if there is a significant difference in mortality between the two groups (kidney injury vs no kidney injury).

```
|          | Kidney injury | No kidney injury
| Died     | 57            | 98
| Survived | 364           | 1902
```

Thank you

Comment: You could use something like a chi-square test or compare two binomial distributions.

Comment: Any of: Chisquare, binomial proportion test, CMH test, Fisher exact test, Logistic regression

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Fisher exact test: proportion surviving not equal between injury and no injury.

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm bored and have time to kill...

## Chiqsuare Test

```
m<- matrix(c(57, 364, 98, 1902), nrow = 2)
chisq.test(m)
```

## Fisher Exact Test

```
m<- matrix(c(57, 364, 98, 1902), nrow = 2)
fisher.test(m)
```

## Logistic Regression

```
data<-tibble::tribble(~Died, ~Injury, ~Weight,
                      1, 'No Kidney Injury', 98,
                      1, 'Kidney Injury', 57,
                      0, 'Kidney Injury', 364,
                      0, 'No Kidney Injury', 1902)

model = glm(Died~Injury, data = data, family = binomial(), weights = Weight)

summary(model)
```